# Como quebrar o texto da legenda no R

Tags: r, plot, legenda-de-gráfico

Preciso plotar uma legenda que tem um texto muito grande. Mas o problema é que quando vou exportar a figura do R, parte do texto fica fora da área do plot. Gostaria de saber se tem como eu quebrar o texto da legenda em duas partes, para que ele caiba na área do plot.

O que eu tenho:

```
texto1 <- "Esse texto é muito grande e portanto precisa ser quebrado em duas partes"
texto2 <- "Esse texto também é muito grande e precisa ser quebrado em duas partes"

plot(NULL, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", bty="n", ylab="", xlab="", xlim=0:1, ylim=0:1)
    
legend("center", legend = c(texto1,texto2), pch=15, pt.cex=3, cex=1.1, bty="n",
       col = c("red", "blue"), y.intersp =1.5)
```

Comment: Você tentou usar uma quebra de linha `\n`?

Comment: @Lucas Nunca tinha usado essa quebra de linha. Mas ela faz exatamente o que eu preciso. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Eis uma função simples para quebrar a linha em quantos pedaços quiser (dois por padrão):

```
div.texto <- function(string, n = 2) {
  comp <- (nchar(string)/n)*1.2
  paste(strwrap(string, comp), collapse = "\n")
}
```

*nchar* dá o número de caracteres em uma string. *strwrap* quebra um texto em pedaços de no máximo o tamanho especificado (por isso o `*1.2`; o tamanho de cada bloco variará de acordo com o tamanho das palavras, não há como garantir o número exato de divisões). O código `\n` indica quebra de linha.

```
plot(NULL, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", bty="n", ylab="", xlab="", xlim=0:1, ylim=0:1)
legend("center", 
       legend = c(div.texto(texto1), div.texto(texto2, 3)),
       pch=15, pt.cex=3, cex=1.1, bty="n", col = c("red", "blue"), y.intersp =1.5)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]